AAOS (Android Automotive OS) for pixel build error
I'm now following the guide from latest Google for using Pixel phone for Android Automotive OS feature.
But, I got the build error when starting, please let us know what is the issue currently?
[100% 1/1\] analyzing Android.bp files and generating ninja file at out/soong/build.aosp_tangorpro_car.ninja
FAILED: out/soong/build.aosp_tangorpro_car.ninja
cd "$(dirname "out/host/linux-x86/bin/soong_build")" && BUILDER="$PWD/$(basename "out/host/linux-x86/bin/soong_build")" && cd / && env -i  "$BUILDER"     --top "$TOP"     --soong_out "out/soong"     --out "out"     --soong_variables out/soong/soong.aosp_tangorpro_car.variables -o out/soong/build.aosp_tangorpro_car.ninja --globListDir aosp_tangorpro_car --globFile out/soong/globs-aosp_tangorpro_car.ninja -l out/.module_paths/Android.bp.list --available_env out/soong/soong.environment.available --used_env out/soong/soong.environment.used.aosp_tangorpro_car.build Android.bp
error: packages/modules/Permission/tests/cts/permission/AppThatRequestContactsPermission15/Android.bp:21:1: "CtsAppThatRequestsContactsPermission15" depends on undefined module "cts_defaults".
Or did you mean \["mts_defaults" "sts_defaults"\]?
error: packages/modules/Permission/tests/cts/permission/AppThatAlsoDefinesPermissionGroupADifferentCert/Android.bp:21:1: "CtsAppThatAlsoDefinesPermissionGroupADifferentCert" depends on undefined module "cts_defaults".
Or did you mean \["mts_defaults" "sts_defaults"\]?
error: packages/modules/HealthFitness/tests/integrationtests/TestApp/Android.bp:49:1: "HCPermsTestAppNoUsageIntent" depends on undefined module "cts_defaults".
Or did you mean \["mts_defaults" "sts_defaults"\]?
error: packages/modules/Permission/tests/cts/permission/AppWithSharedUidThatRequestLocationPermission29/Android.bp:21:1: "CtsAppWithSharedUidThatRequestsLocationPermission29" depends on undefined module "cts_defaults".
Or did you mean \["mts_defaults" "sts_defaults"\]?

Follwoing the Google guide.
Code sync and build
To sync Android build AP1A.240405.002 :
mkdir aaos_on_pixel
cd aaos_on_pixel
REPO_ALLOW_SHALLOW=0 repo init -c -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-14.0.0_r30 --use-superproject --partial-clone --partial-clone-exclude=platform/frameworks/base --clone-filter=blob:limit=10M
repo sync -j32
Download the vendor image for pixel devices from developers.google.com for AP1A.240405.002
curl --output - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/aosp/google_devices-tangorpro-ap1a.240405.002-8d141153.tgz  | tar -xzvf -
tail -n +315 extract-google_devices-tangorpro.sh | tar -zxvf -
Take a patch
cd packages/services/Car
git fetch https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/services/Car refs/changes/83/3037383/2 && git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD #fix the audio crash
cd -
Run the build. :
. build/envsetup.sh
lunch aosp_tangorpro_car-ap1a-userdebug
m

It seems like the error indicates you have a reference to an undefined module named cts_defaults. Can you share where this module is defined and how it is referenced in the relevant files?

@tomerpacific I did not change any code after repo sync guided from Google. I just use
REPO_ALLOW_SHALLOW=0 repo init -c -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-14.0.0_r30 --use-superproject --partial-clone --partial-clone-exclude=platform/frameworks/base --clone-filter=blob:limit=10M
